# access hashes of hashes values in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a nested hashes in ruby and I need to access a specific value of it. My hash look like below.

```
hash = 

    {"list"=>
      {"0"=>
        {"date"=>"11/03/2014",
         "item1"=>"",
         "tiem2"=>"News",
         "item3"=>"",
         "item4"=>"",
         "item5"=>"Videos",
         "Type"=>"Clip"},
       "1"=>
         {"date"=>"11/03/2014",
         "item1"=>"",
         "tiem2"=>"News",
         "item3"=>"",
         "item4"=>"",
         "item5"=>"Videos",
         "Type"=>"Program"}
    }}
```

I need to access the value of "Type" of each keys. 
I tried with the below code but I am not sure why it didn't work.

```
hash_type = hash["list"].keys.each {|key| puts key["Type"]}
```

But it returned the list of keys. i.e 0 and 1

Please help.

Comment: Since your keys are strings, this would work: `h.to_s.scan(/(?<=\"Type\"=>\")[^\"]+/) => ["Clip", "Program"]` (but I wouldn't do it that way).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
hash["list"].map {|_, hash| hash['Type']}
```

Explanation:

```
hash = {key: 'value'}
```

You can loop over a hash using `each` like this:

```
hash.each {|pair| puts pair.inspect }    #=> [:key, 'value']
```

or like this

```
hash.each {|key, value| puts "#{key}: #{value}"} #=> key: value
```

Since we don't use key anywhere, some of the IDEs will complain about unused local variable `key`. To prevent this it is ruby convention to use `_` for variable name and all the IDEs will not care for it to be unused.

Comment: That was awesome. Though I am not sure how it works and what happens inside map block, I liked it. Where can I find the documentation/reference link for it (|_, hash|)so that I can understand it.

Answer (score 2):

```
hash['list'].collect { |_, value| value['Type'] }
 => ["Clip", "Program"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is following your logic (some answers posted different ways to do this). The reason why you go things wrong, if we go step by step is:

```
hash_type = hash["list"].keys #=> ["0", "1"]
```

So everything after that is the same like:

```
["0", "1"].each {|key| puts key["Type"]}
```

So you're basically doing puts `'1'['Type']` and `'0'['Type']` which both evaluate to `nil` (try it in IRB) . Try replacing the `puts` with `p` and you'll get nil printed 2 times. The reason why you're getting `hash_type` to be ["0", "1"] is because your last expression is `keys.each` and `each` ALWAYS return the "receiver", that is the array on which you called `each` (as we saw earlier, that array is ["0", "1"]).

The key to solving this, following your particular logic, is to put the "keys" (which are '0' and '1' in this instance) in the appropriate **context**, and putting them in a context would look something like this:

```
hash_type = hash["list"].keys.each {|key| puts hash["list"][key]["Type"]}`
```

This will print the keys. However, hash_type will still be ["0", "1"] (remember, `each` returns the value of the receiver). If you want the actual type values to be stored in hash_types, replace `each` with `map` and remove `puts`:

```
hash_type = hash["list"].keys.map {|key|  hash["list"][key]["Type"]} #=> ["Clip", "Program"]
```

Comment: This still does not return what the OP needs (`hash_type` ends up containing the list of keys)

Comment: That also worked. I was under the assumption that the when you pass the each key of hash["list"].keys, then we would be able to access key["Type"] like we do in a normal hash.